# Sequelize ExpressJS Using Id for Post Method

Tags: node.js, express, sequelize.js

I have a form that is being used to edit and update the record of a specific Id and I'm able to access the Id within my GET method for my route with `req.params.annotationId`, but when I try to use the POST version of getting a parameter with `req.body.annotationId` I get a value returned of `NULL`. I also tried to use `req.params.annotationId` and it returned the `:annotationId` placeholder for the route. Is this because the field is not present in the form? which would make sense because body-parser looks for values present in the fields?

This is the resulting query from the POST method:

```
Executing (default): SELECT `annotation_id` AS `annotationId`, `annotation_date` AS `annotationDate`,`user_id` AS `userId`, `createdAt`, `updatedAt`, `userUserId` FROM `annotation` AS `annotation` WHERE `annotation`.`user_id` = 1 AND `annotation`.`annotation_id` = NULL LIMIT 1;
```

Here is my route:

```
appRoutes.route('/edit/:annotationId')

    .get(function(req, res){
        console.log('This is the url path ' + req.originalUrl);

        console.log(req.params.annotationId);

        models.Annotation.find({
                where: {
                    userId: req.user.user_id,
                    annotationId: req.params.annotationId
                },attributes: ['annotationId', 'annotationDate']
            }).then(function(annotation){
                res.render('pages/annotation-edit.hbs',{
                    annotation: annotation,
                    user: req.user,
                    editMode: req.originalUrl
                });
        })          
    })


    .post(function(req, res){

        console.log("POST method triggered");

        console.log(req.params.annotationId);

        models.Annotation.find({
            where: {
                    userId: req.user.user_id,
                    annotationId: req.body.annotationId
            }
        }).then(function(annotation){
                if (annotation) {
                    console.log("Annotation exists");
                    annotation.update({
                        annotationDate: req.body.annotationDate,
                        userId: req.user.user_id
                    }).success(function() {
                        console.log("Annotation Updated");
                    });
                }
            })
        });
```

Here is my annotation model:

```
  module.exports = function(sequelize, DataTypes) {

    var Annotation = sequelize.define('annotation', {
        annotationId: {
            type: DataTypes.INTEGER,
            field: 'annotation_id',
            autoIncrement: true,
            primaryKey: true
        },
        annotationDate: {
            type: DataTypes.DATE,
            field: 'annotation_date'
        },
        userId: {
            type: DataTypes.STRING,
            field: 'user_id'
        }
    },

     {
        freezeTableName: true,
        },
        classMethods: {
            associate: function(db) {
                Annotation.belongsTo(db.User)
            }
        }
    });
        return Annotation;
    }
```

Here is the form for the POST request:

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-8 col-md-offset-2">
        <div class="annotation-form">
            <form action="/app/edit/:annotationId" method="post">
                <div class="annotation-form-header">
                    <img class="user-image" src="http://placehold.it/80x80" alt="Generic placeholder image">
                    <label for="annotation-date">Annotation Date:</label>
                    <input type="date" name="annotationDate" id="annotation-form-date" value="{{annotation.annotationDate}}">
                </div>
                <button type="submit" id="create-annotation-button">Update Annotation</button>
            </form>
```

Answer (score 0):

`req.body.annotationId` with get annotationID from data in form like :

```
<form action="/app/edit" method="post">
                <input name="annotationId" type="hidden" value="121313">
                <div class="annotation-form-header">
                    <img class="user-image" src="http://placehold.it/80x80" alt="Generic placeholder image">
                    <label for="annotation-date">Annotation Date:</label>
                    <input type="date" name="annotationDate" id="annotation-form-date" value="{{annotation.annotationDate}}">
                </div>
                <button type="submit" id="create-annotation-button">Update Annotation</button>
            </form>
```

```

`req.params.annotationId` get annotationID from URL : `/edit/4465465`

`<form action="/app/edit/:annotationId" method="post">` <- invalid URL

Comment: Thanks for your answer. The hidden field seems to fix the SQL query that is made with the correct value for the ID, but I get an endless loop on form submission. The reason I use `/app/edit/:annotationId` is because it is my routing for bot the get and post method. I split out the route to have the post come from `/app/edit` and the same endless loop occurred. Any idea why that might be?

Comment: you need response on Post method, should add catch logic if error

Comment: I added `}).catch(function(error){
      res.send(error);
     })`, but there is no error triggered. I did notice that my `     console.log("Annotation exists");
` console.log is not being triggered. Could this be a sign that the issue exists before my `.update` method?

Comment: I figured out the issue, I needed to us `.update` instead of `.find` and then place the `where` clause within the update method

Answer (score 0):

The form should use the handlebars object to pass in the current Id selected like so,

```
<form action="/app/edit/{{annotation.annotationId}}" method="post">
                <input name="annotationId" type="hidden" value="121313">
                <div class="annotation-form-header">
                    <img class="user-image" src="http://placehold.it/80x80" alt="Generic placeholder image">
                    <label for="annotation-date">Annotation Date:</label>
                    <input type="date" name="annotationDate" id="annotation-form-date" value="{{annotation.annotationDate}}">
                </div>
                <button type="submit" id="create-annotation-button">Update Annotation</button>
            </form>
```

The route should then be change from `.find` to `.update`:

```
.post(function(req, res){

        console.log("POST method triggered");

        console.log(req.params.annotationId);

        models.Annotation.update({
            annotationId: req.body.annotationId,
            annotationDate: req.body.annotationDate,
        },{where:{
            userId: req.user.user_id,
            annotationId: req.body.annotationId
        }}).then(function(){
            console.log("Annotation was Updated");
            res.redirect('/app');
        });
    });
```